# Where to put binary assemblies in a moderately small .net project

Tags: .net

I'd like to use Unity and AntiXss in my mvc project. Could you share your ideas how to put the assembilies in to the svn repository so that other developers would be able to simply checkout the code and start work immediately (without installation of the libraries)?

For example in java world it is common for small project to create a lib folder with all the necessary jars. I'm thinking about similar solution for .net and visual studio.

How do you manage your external dependencies?

Note: I don't need to use any other build system/dependency manager than visual studio provides. 
(At least not at this stage of the project)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I put mine 3rd party libs/assemblies in a folder at the root project level /Assemblies parallel with the other project assemblies.

Comment: +1 - I usually do something similar by I usually call the directory "lib"

Comment: Do you create a project called Assemblies? (I'm not sure if I understood you correctly)

Comment: Nope. Just the files as @Phillip Ngans notes below, I include the assemblies as references in any project that requires them.

Answer (score 1):

Check-in these assemblies as standalone files in SVN in a place that is alongside the root of your other projects. You can call this folder 'External'. The act of referencing these assemblies in your project will cause them to be copied to the outbin bin directory when the project is built.